# Configuring MySQL for Power Failure

Tags: mysql, innodb, recovery, crash

I have an embedded device running a MySQL database with a web based application.

The problem is when I shutdown my embedded device it just cuts off the power, and I can not have a controlled shutdown. Given this situation how can I configure MySQL to prevent it from failures and in case of a failure, I should have maximum support to recover my database.

While searching this, I came across InnoDB Engine as well as some configuration options to set like `sync_binlog=1` & `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1`. I have noticed my default Engine is InnoDB and binary logs are also enabled.

What are other configurations to make for best possible failure & recovery support?

I have absolutely no experience with databases and MySQL.

Comment: It might just be me but it seems like you are flirting with an XY problem. An embedded device running a MySQL database and a web server seems like you're asking a lot, or using some very customized hardware that isn't applicable to our general audience.  Regardless you are probably going to need some specialized code/fail safes if you expect power to be cut at any time. This isn't the standard operating model of most RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

You can do many things to prevent this.

1. Move DB server to somewhere else (hosting)
2. Buy an UPS
3. Change to a simpler DB software (SQLite, Files)
4. Make your code to always save the latest changes, so when power up, programs keep running from last saved point.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most important actions, in your code, is to use transaction. This way, you can be sure that a write has been correctly applied to the database in case of a power failure. This is one of the details that needs to be used to ensure the data integrity.